# Server - Cache - Error shows me only code when hitting back

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, passenger, ubuntu-10.04

The weirdest thing happens when I hit back/forward on my application that I've built. It only shows me the raw code from one of the javascriptfiles that I've written.

What could be the main cause of this? I don't know where to begin, and to look after what?

The application is a Ruby On Rails that runs on a Ubuntu Server with Passenger installed that handles the application.

I suspect it has to do something with caching?

Comment: what is your passenger configuration? do you use nginx?

Comment: @Chamnap I use Apache2, let me fetch the conf.

Comment: @Chamnap

Exactly what do you mean with passenger conf? I mean, its a gem, I haven't made any configuration to it at all more than in "mods_enabled" ?

Comment: I use nginx + passenger. I never got problems with that. I don't know how to use apache. :(